# Why am i recieving this attribute error when using the requests module?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, cgi

I am trying to run this code:

```
import requests
import json
page = requests.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')
```

But i continue to recieve this error:

`AttributeError: module 'cgi' has no attribute 'FieldStorage'`

This code works on one of my computers, but not the other.
Any ideas? Also, i'm not even using the cgi module, so I don't know where this is coming from.

Below is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Larson/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36- 
32/tetshjwbrifvheruiher.py", line 2, in <module>
import requests
File "C:\Users\Larson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\requests\__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
from . import utils
File "C:\Users\Larson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\requests\utils.py", line 11, in <module>
import cgi
File "C:/Users/Larson/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32\cgi.py", line 
2, in <module>
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
AttributeError: module 'cgi' has no attribute 'FieldStorage'
```

Comment: What's the full error with trace?

Comment: I added the full traceback